# Ways to send system emails over Gmail Workspace and SMTP server

Tags: smtp, gmail, nodemailer, google-workspace

I have an app built with Node.js and running in Google Cloud. I need to sand certain system emails such as setting change confirmation, password reset tokens, etc. I use nodemailer and Google SMTP server for sending such mails. Till now I used a simple Gmail account like *myaccount@gmail.com* for this purpose. But now I want to send it from *no-replay@mydomain.com*.

My question is whether I need to create a new user in my Google Workspace (and pay monthly for it) for this purpose, or there is another way?

Comment: I think you will need a new smtp provider, for example: AWS SES (very cheap in my experience) https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/

Answer (score 0):

To use all the core services in Google Workspace you need to pay at least for the business standard edition $6 per month.

It's good if you're going to use it as a permanent or business solution. But if it's just for testing it's not worthy. It's better a trial.

As an alternative solution, if you have a cheaper SMTP server, you can add that email address as [Send mail as](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370) in your free Gmail account and configure an alias in nodemailer

```
var mailOptions = {
       to: user.email,
       from: 'Domain Email <example@domain.com>',
       subject: subject,
       html: emailHTML
};
```